# *.rsa and *.sf manifest.mf calling from java class

Tags: java, security, rsa

I had resigned a jar file and runned it. However, it is closed itself immediately after opening. Is it possible to call infromation of *.rsa or *.sf or manifest.mf from java code to check it if changed or not, thank you.

Comment: When I put original *.rsa, *.sf, and manifest.mf its works just fine..

Comment: Open a DOS Box and run it so you can read the error message.

Comment: What have been changed prior to the resigning ?

Comment: Actually I had changed something, but it didnt worked. Then I think it might be problem about resigning, and I had just exported as zip original file and deleted just META-INF/ (*.rsa, *.sf) files and resigned it againd. But it gets my attention now resigned jar file have META-INF/ (*.dsa, *.sf) files. is it big difference that dsa instead of rsa, if it is how to sign like original in ubuntu os, thank you.

Comment: I had signed jar file with rsa, gived that warning:  Warning: 
"The signer certificate is not yet valid.
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2015-06-04) or after any future revocation date." However, it is not working again..

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a method in the class of jar file and its returning certificates, that means yes in jar file there is a certificate control bridge, code is:

```
    private Certificate[] XQ(et etProp) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Rg test 78");
    String value = null;
    Iterator iterator = etProp.af().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        un.JI innerUn = (un.JI) iterator.next();
        String certificateToUpperCase = innerUn.XQ().toUpperCase();


        if (certificateToUpperCase != null && certificateToUpperCase.startsWith("META-INF/")
                && (certificateToUpperCase.endsWith(".RSA") || certificateToUpperCase.endsWith(".DSA"))) {

            value = innerUn.XQ();
            break;
        }

    }

    if (value == null) {
                System.out.println("Rg test 81");
        qm.XQ((String) "Could not find certificates file");
        return null;
    } else {
                System.out.println("Rg test 82");
        byte[] arrayAf = etProp.af(value);
        if (arrayAf == null) {
                        System.out.println("Rg test 83");
            Object[] objectsArray = new Object[] { value };
            return null;
        } else {
                        System.out.println("Rg test 84");
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(arrayAf);

            Collection collection;
            try {
                                System.out.println("Rg test 85");
                CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory
                        .getInstance("X.509");
                collection = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(byteArrayInputStream);
            } catch (CertificateException ex) {
                qm.XQ((String) String.format(
                        "Could not parse certificate data: %s",
                        new Object[] { ex.toString() }));
                return null;
            }

            Certificate[] certificates = new Certificate[collection.size()];
            int i = 0;

            Certificate certificate;
            for (Iterator iterator1 = collection.iterator(); iterator1.hasNext(); certificates[i++] = certificate) {
                                System.out.println("Rg test 87");
                certificate = (Certificate) iterator1.next();
            }

            return certificates;
        }
    }
}
```

It is very nice move to protect jar file from cracking.